# Azure Search -- Want random result set

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm playing around with replacing an ElasticSearch cluster with an Azure Search service, mainly due to infrastructure hosting/monitoring concerns.  So far, things are going decently, but one of the scenarios I need to account for is retrieving 10 random results for a query.  In ElasticSearch, we just used the RandomScore function from the Nest library which was good enough.

I've read a bit on Scoring Profiles, but that doesn't seem to fit what I need, as it doesn't have a Random ScoringAggregationFunction.

Is there something I'm missing on how to do this natively?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get randomly sorted results in Azure Search. Please request this feature on our UserVoice to help us prioritize: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search

A workaround may be to add a field to your index that is populated with some randomly generated integer within some range at index time. When you would call for 10 random documents, your application would instead randomly generate integers within that range to create a filter clause on that field to get randomized results.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that.  I was planning something similar to your workaround, just in case.  Looks like I'll have to pull that trigger.

Thanks for the info!

Comment: Stumbling on the same requirements I have documented our workaround [here](https://medium.com/@yoad/pseudo-random-sorting-with-azure-search-28966ad851ae)

Comment: This workaround doesn't always work for smaller data sets where you might not even have 10 documents in total with the same randomly generated integer, resulting in certain repeats. A truly random workaround would be to target any UUID that you may have in the document, and setup an interpreter before fetching the documents, the interpreter prioritizes documents based on the alphabetical priority of the n-th character in the UUID, where n is randomly generated and max value same as the UUID max length.

Answer (score 1):

Trying this at the moment.  I'm using a two step process:

1. Generate your query but set `$count=true` and `$top=0`.  The query result should contain a field named @odata.count.
2. You can then randomly pick an int between 0 and @odata.count then use `$top=1` and `$skip=<random number>` to return a single random entry.  There is one caveat: [$skip will only accept numbers less than 100000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#skip-optional)